# What's the best way to detach a Collection from a Map in Java?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I obtain a HashSet from a HashMap and I don't want that my modifications on the HashSet reflect on the HashMap values.

What's the best way of doing something like this :

```
HashSet<Object> hashset = new HashSet((Collection<Object>) hashmap.values());
//Something like ...
hashset.detach();
//Then i can modify the HashSet without modifying the HashMap values
```

**Edit :**
I have to modify an element in the HashSet but I don't want to modify this same element in the HashMap.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the `HashSet` from `hashMap.values()` like this, then it's already "detached" in the sense that modifying the `HashSet` will not influence the map it was constructed from.

However, if you modify an object *inside* the set (for example calling a setter on it), then those changes will be reflected inside the `HashMap` as well (since the `Set` and the `Map` will refer to the same object).

One way around this is to make [defensive copies](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DefensiveCopy) of each element (using `clone()` or by using a copy constructor).

Another way is to use [immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Comment: Using clone() or new HashSet<Object>(object) don't work .. the modification of an element is reflected in the HashMap.

Comment: @elbanco: I meant that you use `clone()` on *each element in the `Set`*. If you only clone the `Set` itself, then that will have no effect.

Answer (score 6):

If you're creating a *new* `HashSet` as per the first line of your code snippet, that's already a separate collection. Adding or removing items from the set won't change your `hashMap`. Modifying the *existing* items will, of course - but that's a different matter, and will almost always be a Very Bad Thing (assuming your modifications affect object equality).

Answer (score 1):

You are close:

```
Set<Object> set =  hashmap.values(); // is backed by the map

// create a new hashset seeded from the other set
Set<Object> hashset = new HashSet<Object>(set);
```

Comment: It don't work .. the modification of an element is reflected in the HashMap.

Comment: Then you are changing elements within the set (rather than changing *which* elements are in the set).  For this, you need to copy each element into the new set, as others have said.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to copy the values, and change the state of the values you need to create a deep copy, which relies on knowing how to create copies of the objects held in the `Map` as values.  Hopefuly this test illustrates what I mean.

```
@Test
public void testHashMap() throws Exception {
    final Map<Integer, TestContainer<Double>> hashmap = new HashMap<Integer, TestContainer<Double>>();
    final TestContainer<Double> t1 = new TestContainer<Double>(1d);
    final TestContainer<Double> t2 = new TestContainer<Double>(2d);
    hashmap.put(1, t1);
    hashmap.put(2, t2);

    // create a separate collection which can be modified
    final Set<TestContainer<Double>> hashset = new HashSet<TestContainer<Double>>(hashmap.values());
    assertEquals(2, hashmap.size());
    assertEquals(2, hashset.size());

    hashset.remove(t2);

    assertEquals(2, hashmap.size());
    assertEquals(1, hashset.size());

    // prove that we cannot modify the contents of the collection
    hashset.iterator().next().o += 1;

    assertEquals(2d, t1.o, 0d);
}

private static final class TestContainer<T> {
    private T o;

    private TestContainer(final T o) {
        this.o = o;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public MyType cloneObject(MyType o) {
    MyType clone = new MyType();
    // TODO copy the attributes of 'o' to 'clone' return the clone
    return clone; 
}

public void populateHashSet(HashMap<Object,MyType> hashMap) {
    HashSet<MyType> hashSet = new HashSet<MyType>();
    for (MyType o : hashMap.values()) {
        hashSet.add(cloneObject(o));
    }
}
```

That said, I would be very careful about making copies of objects unless all the attributes of the object are primitive/immutable types. If you just copy an attribute object reference to an object reference in the clone then your 'clone' can still produce side-effects in the original object by changing the objects it references.